# Where did the Trade Federation ships go in the Phantom Menace?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace, deleted-scenes

In the opening scenes of The Phantom Menace we see the Trade Federation blockade of Naboo which features a fleet of many capital ships. In the climactic battle at the end of the film there appears to be exactly one capital ship. Where did the others go? Is there a deleted or even unfilmed scene that explains this?

Comment: I don't know if this question deserves an upvote or a stiff drink.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They went back into Trade Federation space, presumably.

> A single battleship orbited the planet, all that remained of the Trade
> Federation blockade. Housed within was the control station responsible
> for directing the droid army that occupied Naboo. **When Panaka wondered
> aloud at the absence of the other battleships, Qui-Gon pointed out
> rather dryly that you don’t need a blockade once you control the port.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Phantom Menace: Official Novelisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_I_%E2%80%93_The_Phantom_Menace_(novel))</sup></sub>

and

> Everyone grew tense as they neared Naboo, but when they came out of hyperspace at last, no Trade Federation ships hung between them and the planet. **“The blockade is gone!” Captain Panaka said in surprise.
>
> “The war’s over,” Obi-Wan said. “No need for it now.”**
> “I have one battleship on my scope,” Ric Olié said.
> Obi-Wan glanced over and nodded. “The Droid Control Ship.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Phantom Menace: Official Junior Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

Since the droids on the ground control all of the major loading docks and spaceports, there's nothing *to* blockade any more. The planet has been garrisoned and the fleet can leave.

This was also addressed by Pablo Hidalgo in [Star Wars Insider #80](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_80)

> **Q. I noticed in the beginning of Episode 1 that there are several Trade
> Federation ships blockading Naboo. Why does this number change from
> several down to one toward the end of the film?**
>
> **PH:** Several lines of dialogue were trimmed in the edit of Episode I, but
> can still be found in the Illustrated Screenplay published in 1999.
> Upon emerging from hyperspace over Naboo, Captain Panaka notes "*The
> blockade's gone.*" Obi-Wan dryly add, "*The war's over...no need for
> it now.*"   Given that the Trade Federation had rounded all the Naboo
> citizenry into camps and was on the verge of signing a treaty to
> legitimize their occupation, the frugal Nute Gunray reassigned his
> costly blockade prematurely, thinking he was on the eve of victory.

Comment: Its amazing how many holes seem to get papered over in these novelisations